# Why docker-compose and dockerfile working this way?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I don't know why docker-compose and dockerfile work like this.

1. This is my repository
   DockerCompose
   ├ node
   │ ├node_modules(dir)
   │ ├index.js
   │ ├nodeStart.sh
   │ ├package.json
   │ └package-lock.json
   └ docker-compose.yml
2. docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3.8"
    services:
     node:
        container_name: "node"
        image: node:latest
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: node/Dockerfile
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=development
        expose:
          - "3000"
        tty: true
```

3. node/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
MAINTAINER Parksy

WORKDIR /home/
COPY ../node ./node
WORKDIR /home/node
RUN npm install && npm update
RUN npm install express mysql
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/node/nodeStart.sh"]
```

If I execute `docker-compose build` on settings like this...

```
1. .yml -> context: . 
          dockerfile: ./node/Dockerfile

   Dockerfile -> 1) COPY ../node ./node (works!!)
                 2) COPY ./ ./node (error!!)

2. .yml -> context: ./node 
          dockerfile: Dockerfile 

   Dockerfile -> 1) COPY ./ ./node (works!!) 
                 2) COPY ../node ./node (error!!)
```

1-2 error msg

```
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN npm install && npm update                                                                                                                                      0.7s 
------
 > [5/6] RUN npm install && npm update:
#9 0.683 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#9 0.683 npm ERR! syscall open
#9 0.684 npm ERR! path /home/node/package.json
#9 0.685 npm ERR! errno -2
#9 0.686 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/node/package.json'
#9 0.686 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
#9 0.687 npm ERR! enoent
#9 0.689
#9 0.689 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 0.689 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-21T14_20_53_627Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install && npm update]: exit code: 254
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build : Build failed
```

2-2 error msg

```
 => ERROR [3/6] COPY ../node ./node                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
------
 > [3/6] COPY ../node ./node:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/node" not found: not found
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build : Build failed
```

I think ./ and ../node are same!!
Please explain to me the reason for this

Comment: `../node` is illegal because it takes you out of the "build context". You are only allowed to access files on the host in the build context directory or below it for security reasons. The error message could definitely be better.

Comment: @HansKilian After your answer and my testing, I totally understand this issue. thank you very much!!